# CSS: Help with text under than over

Tags: html, css

Please see this:
[image]

My code looks like this now:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bd9Ut/

As you can see I only managed the get text above.. ("asd"), and i want it under, above the border image..

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What is the point of "IMAGE"? It's text right there. And it's not obvious that the image is the black bar, as you can actually make a black box like that with css.

Comment: @JustcallmeDrago Go into jsfiddle. How does it look? Then check the image, how does it look? What difference is there? The text above the imagebar "i want text here" is where i want text, but i havnt managed to do ti. Forget "IMAGE" I normal have my logo there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
.header-inner-lhs { width: 360px; height: 22px; margin-top: 73px; float: left;  }
```

You can see it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/Bd9Ut/4/

I simply adjusted the height down and added a top margin to keep the overall height the same, maintaining the overall element height at 95px;

Is that what you had in mind?